# How to install pythonnet in alpine 3.8

Tags: c#, python-3.x, alpine-linux, python.net

I need to install pythonnet in fresh alpine 3.8/python 3.7 container. I've already done it for Ubuntu (great help here was dockerfile for pythonnet). I cannot use apt-get in alpine, only apk commands, which don't see any mono-complete or nuget (I think that installing these will allow me to install pythonnet correctly, especially mono-complete 4.8.0.520-0xamarin3 version). How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome! Could you post the pythonnet Dockerfile you used for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile: Stretch, Python 3.7.4, Mono 5.20.1, Pythonnet 2.4.0

```
# Pythonnet - Dockerfile
# ----------------------------------------------
# * based on debian stretch with python 3.7.4
# * mono 5.20.1 + pythonnet 2.4.0 
# ----------------------------------------------
FROM python:3.7.4-stretch

# [ Mono: 5.20.1 ]
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
  && echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stretch/snapshots/5.20.1/. main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y clang \
  && apt-get install -y mono-complete=5.20.1\* \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

# [ pythonnet 2.4.0 ]
RUN pip install pycparser \
  && git clone https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet \
  && python pythonnet/setup.py bdist_wheel \
  && pip install --no-index --find-links=./pythonnet/dist/ pythonnet
```